# PyCharm and docker compose interpreter

Tags: pycharm

I noticed when running a Python file using the "Run" functionality in PyCharm, while using the interpreter from docker compose, once the file has finished running, the container is terminated. Is there a way to avoid that?

Also, attaching to the container seems to take a bit of time, am I doing something wrong here? should I just resort to having two Python environments? (the one in the Docker container, and a local one for debugging)

Note: I have a `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` in a setup where I don't have to have separate `.dev.yml`/`.prod.yml`, so modifying those too much isn't really an option.